# dynamic value for the data provider in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, dataprovider

I am using lambda for data provider for unit test in python. But if i send static variable means i can get the result. If i use some dynamic variable means i have encountered problem.
And this is my coding

```
class TestOne(unittest.TestCase):

    data=lambda: (
            ((tc.read_data_from_excel('InputData.xls','Data','DataLevel1')),),
        )


    def setUp(self):
        self.driver =webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    @data_provider(data)
    def test(self,username,password):        
        //coding here
```

Here the excel file having username and password and write method 'read_data_from_excel' to retrieve the data and return as list. Where i did wrong

Comment: what is your problem? can you provide a stacktrace or the error you're getting?

Comment: test() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)